# Expected Declaration Swift (Sprite Kit)

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I'm using Xcode 7 with swift and when I type

```
class Block {
var Block = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
Block.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()                            //Error Here
Block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
Block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
Block.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
Block.physicsbody?.LinearDamping = 0
self.addChild(Block)
```

It gives me an error that says "expected declaration" (on the line with the comment) and I don't know why

Comment: Try saving your file (cmd+s), deleting the line and retyping it, or cleaning your project (shift+cmd+k IIRC). Does the error stay?

Answer (score 1):

There are some errors:

- You have a class and are trying to change class properties outside the scope of a method or an initializer.
- The line `Block.physicsbody?.LinearDamping = 0` should be `Block.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0`; case-sensitivity.
- You name your `SKShapeNode` instance as `Block`, the same name as your class. By naming convention, class (type) names begin with `Capital` letters, whereas class properties use `small` letters in their names.

With these three fixed, we can proceed to looking at your scene.

With help from Leo Dabus (thanks!), we should have enough to set you up with a minimal working example (using your code) of the `SKScene`:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let block = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)

        // you will also need to set your node initial position 
        // if you would like your red circle to fall from the middle of the top of your scene you need to use the scene frame midX and maxY (not the view frame). the scene it is not necessarily the same size of your view) 
        block.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.frame.midX, y: scene!.frame.maxY)

        block.fillColor = SKColor.redColor()
        block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 15)
        block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = true
        block.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
        block.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
        self.addChild(block)
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: self.addChild there would be referencing to the class Block it needs to be at the game scene method didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

Comment: class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks! Just added an edit about the naming convention. I'm not very well-versed with SK, I'll add your help into the answer. Feel free to edit it afterwards if I got something wrong.

Comment: you should declare it as "let block = ... " creates an instance of it. You will still be able to change its properties declaring it as a constant

Comment: you can declare it also inside didMoveToView let block = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15). it won't go out of existence once the method finishes. Only declare it at class level if you need to access it  (change its properties later) outside that method

Comment: @LeoDabus This was a good example of blind posting, indeed >< Sorry about that; I ran it in the playground without any error, by I guess it's a different story for a real project. I'll excuse myself for sleep now, and next time an initial answer about some code errors turns into Sprite Kit details, I'll probably be best off leaving that to other answerers (until I dwell into it myself!). Thanks for your help, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: you need to set the node initial position block.position = CGPoint(x: scene!.frame.midX, y: scene!.frame.maxY) to make the red dot start at the top of the game scene and fall through the screen